# How to underline selected option in field select

Tags: html, jsp, html-select, underline

Excuse me for elementary question. I am the beginner.

How to make selected value in field `select` underlined, but another items (`options`) in corresponding list are not underlined?

Unfortunately  when I use attribute `style="text-decoration: none"` to tag `select`, and attribute `style="text-decoration: lined-through"` to selected `option`, in result selected value in field `select` isn’t underlined.

By the other hand, when I use attribute `style="text-decoration: lined-through"` to tag `select` **all** corresponding `options` become underlined too (despite of **`style="text-decoration:none"`**).

Comment: Please post some HTML. It is not easy to guess what you mean

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is ":checked".

```
select option:checked { 
   text-decoration: lined-through; /*or underline if you want*/
}
```

Comment: excuse me, but do you mean css or javascript?